# Tensorflow / Deepmind: how do I take actions from observations for math algorithms related to proofs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, proof-general

This question is to ask for directions/suggestions/help on the use of deepmind opensource libraries: https://github.com/deepmind/lab or https://www.tensorflow.org/ in Python.

Consider that I'm new to concepts like deep learning and AI.

Questions are:

- Are there examples on using Deepmind or Tensorflow for math problems where I need to observe values and take actions?

Using an approach similar to to the one described in this page (https://deepmind.com/blog/open-sourcing-deepmind-lab/) based on observations, actions, rewards, etc., I'd like to call a learing agent to choose among some values. I was thinking to something like this:

- Input: a list of list of tuple (the list will change at each step)
- Action: pick up a value from the input (based on experience)
- Reward: If the value it returned was good or bad for the rest of the algorithm I'm implementing, I'll reward the deep learning agent.

Additional notes:

- I cannot train the algorith in advance

The Input is something like this (only the numbers):

```
edge: (1, 2), face_down: 4, face_up: 5, face_left: 4, face_right: 5
edge: (0, 1), face_down: 4, face_up: 4, face_left: 4, face_right: 5
edge: (5, 4), face_down: 4, face_up: 5, face_left: 4, face_right: 5
edge: (6, 7), face_down: 3, face_up: 5, face_left: 5, face_right: 5
edge: (3, 0), face_down: 4, face_up: 4, face_left: 5, face_right: 4
edge: (4, 1), face_down: 4, face_up: 5, face_left: 5, face_right: 4
edge: (8, 5), face_down: 4, face_up: 5, face_left: 5, face_right: 4
edge: (3, 8), face_down: 4, face_up: 5, face_left: 4, face_right: 5
edge: (2, 3), face_down: 4, face_up: 5, face_left: 5, face_right: 4
edge: (5, 0), face_down: 4, face_up: 4, face_left: 5, face_right: 4
edge: (0, 5), face_down: 4, face_up: 4, face_left: 4, face_right: 5
edge: (1, 0), face_down: 4, face_up: 4, face_left: 5, face_right: 4
edge: (9, 6), face_down: 3, face_up: 5, face_left: 5, face_right: 5
edge: (0, 3), face_down: 4, face_up: 4, face_left: 4, face_right: 5
edge: (7, 9), face_down: 3, face_up: 5, face_left: 5, face_right: 5
```

The idea is to use the same aproach deepmind uses to play games, but instead of analyzing pixels and use the pad (up, dowm, left, right, fire, jump), is to let the learning agent to analyze some math values and, as the only action, to select one of them.

Are there other approaches or libraries/framework to address such a problem?

[image]

Comment: What did you mean by "edge"?

Comment: Edges and vertices of a graph ... that represent a geographical map.

Comment: Several details are still unclear, for example, are the correct actions (reward) determined by humans or automatically? Are the rewards related only to the immediate previous action? (I'm currently learning reinforcement learning, we could collaborate)

Comment: Reword is given automatically at the end of the algorithm I'm implementing.  Consider that I'm trying to color a graph automatically by choosing the right edge, so after N actions I'll will know if I can reword the NN or not. I better understanding of what I'd like to do is here: https://4coloring.wordpress.com/2016/12/01/four-color-theorem-new-ideas/

Answer (score 0):

In your example, it seems like you're doing a contextual bandit problem. It should be very simple to solve your problem using the Bellman's Equation.

The algorithm will look like this:

1) Feed your math values (states) into your bandit.

2) Allow your bandit to pick what it thinks is the best action (at the beginning this will be random).

3) Obtain the reward for performing that action given those states.

A quick example of the coding and implementation can be found here:

https://medium.com/emergent-future/simple-reinforcement-learning-with-tensorflow-part-1-5-contextual-bandits-bff01d1aad9c

You will just have to change the reward setup and the state setup.